# Doubt about a preposition

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence:

> I still don't know what I'm wearing **to** the living room new year's eve

I would choose *at* as preposition instead of *to*, or I would rephrase it like:

> I still don't know what I'm wearing **to go to** the living room new year's eve

Is that *to* a preposition of place or should I assume it introduces the purpose behind the choice of what to wear?

Comment: "Wear [an outfit] **to** a party" is a normal way to speak of wearing it to attend the party. (The living room is just a room in a house, so you wouldn't wear special clothes to go there!)

Comment: I agree with Kate.  Saying "wear (the clothes) *at* the party" makes it sound you are wearing the clothes when you are at the party, but you did not put them on before, which is confusing.

Comment: It's probably a L1 interference thus. Thank you.

Comment: ["the living room new year's eve" is not grammatical.]

Comment: The sentence is from a vignette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sentence is correct, but it's supposed to be funny because of an unusual situation.

The expression *[ "wear" X "to" Y ]* means you go to Y wearing X. It's used for places outside your home.

In this case, however, it seems that the speaker is spending New Years Eve in their living room. Maybe they're hosting a NYE party, or maybe they're just staying home alone. Either way, they're deciding what to wear for the evening, and intentionally and humorously misuse the expression *[ "wear" X "to" Y ]* to imply that their living room is some special destination that's worth getting dressed up for.

Answer (score 0):

"*I'm wearing [x] to the party*" idiomatically means what you are wearing *for* the party.

Saying "*I'm wearing [x] **to go to** the party*" sounds like you're just wearing it while you travel there.

Comment: Thank you @Astralbee for pointing out that "to wear to" is idiomatic. In my original language, Italian, we use preposition at to convey the same exact meaning.